# How to find best MSAA level available in DXUT's ModifyDeviceSettings function

Tags: c, direct3d, dxut

I'd like to pick a decent MSAA level in the ModifyDeviceSettings callback of the DXUT (d3d11) function, but there's no device pointer available to call CheckMultisampleQualityLevels.

The DXUT function DXUTGetD3D11Device returns null at this point in the init.  There are a number of D3D9 samples that do just what I want, but they rely on the old DXUTGet3DObject (or whatever) call to return the live device pointer, which you don't get in D3D11.

If I just stuff a "4" into pDeviceSettings->d3d11.sd.SampleDesc.Count that works, and if I pick too big of a number it will revert to 1, but I'd like to pick the best available up to but not higher than 4.

Does anyone know how I can enumerate the available multisample levels in the DXUT framework and pick one I feel is best?

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you are using the latest *DXUT for Direct3D11* from [GitHub](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=320437).

DXUT enumerates all the MSAA information as part of the support for settings dialogs in the `CD3D11EnumDeviceSettingsCombo` members `multiSampleCountList` and `multiSampleQualityList`.

That said, the samples that want to enable MSAA 4x 'by default' usually just do:

```
bool CALLBACK ModifyDeviceSettings( DXUTDeviceSettings* pDeviceSettings,
    void* pUserContext )
{
    static bool s_bFirstTime = true;
    if( s_bFirstTime )
    {
        // Enable 4xMSAA by default
        DXGI_SAMPLE_DESC MSAA4xSampleDesc = { 4, 0 };
        pDeviceSettings->d3d11.sd.SampleDesc = MSAA4xSampleDesc;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: I think I said I already know how to stuff a 4 in there, I just don't know how to find out what the device actually supports (mine does 8) in that callback.

Comment: In the ``IsD3D11DeviceAcceptable`` callback, you are given ``CD3D11EnumAdapterInfo`` which you can look at for the list above. If the device doesn't support 8x, you can reject it or you can just remember that fact for the ``ModifyDeviceSettings`` callback.